# Using VBA to insert formula - IF statement

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Im trying to use VBA to insert this formula

`=IF(OR(J2="S06",J2="S07", J2="S08"), "Yes", "No"`

into a range of cells, where the value of J can go from J2, to J(i), i being the last row with data in it, I however cant get that formula to work within VBA. I have a similar one in the same macro that looks like this

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
   truefalse = "=LEFT(A" & i & ",3)"
   Range("J" & i).Value = truefalse
Next i
```

This one works fine, but I cant get the variable on this to set properly, no matter what I try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a loop to do this. `Range("J2:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=LEFT(A2,3)"`.

Comment: Well, what did you you try with that formula?  Note you would use `""` for each single `"` in excel, to allow VBA to input an actual mark.  You can paste that to a range, where the first row of the range matches your formula numbers, and as it goes down the range, will offset any non-fixed values, e.g., `$J1` would update each row and not column as it moves over the range.

Comment: With your original formula, something like: `Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(OR(J2=""S06"",J2=""S07"", J2=""S08""), ""Yes"", ""No"")"`

Comment: Will that change the value of J2 along to J3 and so on?

Comment: `Range.Formula = "=IF(OR(J2={""S06"",""S07"",""S08""}),""Yes"",""No"")"`

Comment: "Will that change the value of J2 along to J3 and so on?" - yes.